# Want to write our custom tag in Apache Camel <when> Conditions

Tags: java, xpath, apache-camel

I have a requirement for Apache Camel to work on custom predicates.

we have Inflight Exchange which has XML Body  which is

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
        <ns1:MSG xmlns:ns1="http://bean.stack.com/MSG">
            <ns1:field ns1:ID="EMP_NAME" ns1:Value="Slok"/>
            <ns1:field ns1:ID="EMP_ID" ns1:Value="ER1234"/>

        </ns1:MSG>
```

I want to do something like

```
                <choice>
                    <when> 
                        <MSG>EMP_ID=='ER1234'</MSG>
                        <to uri="route to specific logic "/>
                    </when>
                </choice>
```

Sometimes , XPath doesn't work for me under ...as Separate File. So decided to do like this.
How can I achieve this , any suggestions ...

Comment: Well, XPath is your safest bet so I suggest figuring out what's going wrong "sometimes". If you still want to go down this route then the easiest way would probably be to marshal it into a POJO and then do something like this: `<simple>${body}.EMP_ID == 'ER1234'</simple>`

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, you cannot just come up with new syntax in the XML DSL. You can use a bean/method call as expression and call a method on a java class where you can write java code as the predicate.

If you want to use XML then XPath/XQuery can be a good option, but they can be tricky to make them correct. Mind about namespaces and other kinds of things. So spend time in an XML tool to write and test your expressions are correct.

Or marshal the XML into POJO using JAXB/JacksonXML,XStream or some other data format/library and work with java code, or simple/groovy expressions.

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I will tried with xpath but having problem with xpath returning NODESET in some cases especially under <Routes>. If i use the same xpath expression under <RouteContext> it works.